# how to use on click send message whatsapp?

Tags: php, whatsapp, sendmessage

I want to send message through whatsapp by link https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber&text=urlencodedtext . But after clicking that link, it will popup whatsapp aplication first. How to pass this ?
 I use function

> $url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber&text=urlencodedtext';
>   file_get_contents($url);